# Why does my system only boot after full power down?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, freeze, reboot

I have Fedora 30 (upgraded over time starting from 28) and after the recent upgrade from 29 to 30, the system no longer works after a reboot, only after a full power down.

What happens when I reboot (i.e. when I type "reboot" as root in the terminal and hit enter) is that after the POST check, the system hangs on a black screen with the text cursor blinking in the top left. I left it on for the whole weekend, no progress.

When I simply boot from a full power down, the system shows no defects. What's odd is that, when I press the physical reset button during the hanging scenario, is that the next boot procedure fails in the same manner, so there must be something that persists somewhere in the system.

I tried everything in grub.cnf but it just doesn't respond to anything in the reboot scenario. Not a single echo command will show anything on the screen.

Why can I only boot after a full power down?

Comment: Sounds like crappy BIOS/UEFI bumped into some ACPI-related regression in  the kernel.

Comment: @TomYan Any idea on how to dive into diagnosing that?

Answer (score 0):

The cause for such problems is often hardware, so you might consider using a
repair-shop that can test swapping out various parts.

The more common causes are:

- Defective PSU
- Bad capacitor on the motherboard
- Bad card (I have seen the graphics card mentioned once in such a case, but it can
  be anything)
- Over-clocking.

What you can do:

- Check if there is a BIOS update (only download from the manufacturer of the
  motherboard)
- Disconnect every device possible and connect again one-by-one
- Visually inspect the motherboard
- Try another PSU.

If you find nothing, the repair-shop may do better.